# TypeScript 2.0 with react-dnd gives error "JSX element attributes may not be a union type"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-dnd

In a TypeScript + React project I am using [react-dnd](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd) with its [DefinitelyTyped typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-dnd):

```
interface ExampleScreenProps { a, b, c }
interface ExampleScreenState { x, y, z }

class ExampleScreen extends React.Component<ExampleScreenProps, ExampleScreenState> { }

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(ExampleScreen);
```

This gets rendered in another component:

```
import ExampleScreen from "./ExampleScreen";

<ExampleScreen a="a" b="b" c="c" />
```

This works in TS 1.8 without any errors. When I upgraded to TS 2.0 I got the following compile error:

> Error:(90, 10) TS2600: JSX element attributes type
>   '(ExampleScreenProps & { children?: ReactNode; }) |
>   (ExampleScreenProps & { children...' may not be a union type.

This is the [type definition for `DragDropContext`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-dnd/index.d.ts#L51-L53):

```
export function DragDropContext<P>(
    backend: Backend
): <P>(componentClass: React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>) => ContextComponentClass<P>;
```

I can't put this together. What is the error complaining about? It seems that it doesn't like the union of `ComponentClass<P> | StatelessComponent<P>`, yet those are not the element attributes, the element attributes are simply `<P>`. I tried explicitly passing `<P>`:

```
export default DragDropContext<ExampleProps>(HTML5Backend)(ExampleScreen);
```

But the same error remains. I can workaround it by asserting the output:

```
export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(ExampleScreen) as React.ComponentClass<ExampleProps>;
```

But I don't like having to use an assertion and I don't understand the actual problem, or if I'm doing something wrong. Is this a problem with the typings that can be fixed?

Comment: Thinking about this, I guess the error may be caused because `<P>` for a component class has the implicit props `{key, children, ref}` but stateless components don't have all of those props, so the result is not the same. Still, I don't see why TS can't infer that the type is a `ComponentClass` and not a `StatelessComponent`.

Comment: If this is the same as [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13526), then apparently it's being addressed in [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12107).

Answer (score 1):

no build error with typescript 2.4.2
and used dependencies:

```
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dnd":"^2.4.0"

    "@types/react": "^16.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/react-dnd":"^2.0.33",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the new typings using:

```
npm i @types/react-dnd --save-dev
```

if you already install other typings remove it using:

```
typings uninstall --save --global react-dnd
```

After that it should work as expected.